# Is it possible to have low level encryption on the disks of a Synology DiskStation DS213J (NAS)?

Tags: security, encryption, nas, disk-encryption

The device in question is a Synology DiskStation DS213J (NAS). I know I can encrypt shared folders, but unfortunately not the home/homes folder. All I want is that if my NAS is stolen than all data is unusable.

I don't need to have different encryption for each user, just a collective one which I manage. I know that TrueCrypt and (I think) Windows with BitLocker can encrypt the disk before you enter the OS. I was thinking the OS of my DiskStation NAS could do something similar.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this can be easily done on a Synology.

You probably have to encrypt on the client. I am for example using a dedicated user to perform backups to the synology (into that user's homedir). I am using duplicity which can do exactly that.

Comment: I was hoping to use Cloud Station. Very similar to Dropbox, but it puts the files in the homes folder which is not possible to encrypt. I ended up using Duplicati (looks similar to Duplicity) for backup over WebDAV (HTTPS) in an encrypted shared folder. It won't synchronize files, however, currently I only have one computer. My other users will have to manage their own synchronization method or use the unencrypted Cloud Station. Thank you for your answer.